# Issue using new-variable in a loop

Tags: powershell

So, I have an interesting problem that I'm having no luck solving.  I have a need to create a bunch of dynamic array variables.

code:

```
$temp = 'arr1=(1,2,3);arr2=(4,5,6);arr3=(7,8,9)'
foreach($item in $temp.split(";")){
    $var = $item.split("=")
    New-variable $var[0] $var[1]
    get-variable $var[0]
}
```

Results:

```
$arr1 (1,2,3)
...   (4,5,6)
...   (7,8,9)
```

I have variable $temp which contains a semicolon delimited list of variables/values I want to create.  As you can see above I am using new-variable to create this.  What is interesting is when I run this from a script, new-variable works for the first call but then I get "..." for all other variables in the array. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: $temp = $arr1=(1,2,3);$arr2=(4,5,6) . Is that temp string ?

Comment: Your first line doesn't make a semicolon delimited list. It stores the 1,2,3 in $temp and creates $arr2 with 4,5,6 but that's it. Please edit your question to fix the syntax.

Comment: It would help to get info *what* is your scenario, rather than the way you tried to solve it. Looking at the way you did it - you probably doing it wrong.. ;) What exactly is "dynamic" in your data and what end results should be - answering those two question would help others to forge some solution or push you in the right direction...

Comment: Sorry, I quickly put this up last night.  Thanks for the help all but I figured this one out.  I am pulling this string from a config file and when I am splitting the the string I was getting some random character inserted.  I fixed this by trimming $var[0].

Answer (score 2):

As Andy already pointed out in a comment, you're not creating a semicolon-separated list, you're creating several variables named `$arr1`, `$arr2`, etc. and `$temp` just refers to `$arr1`.

A way of fixing your code would be

```
$temp = 'arr1=(1,2,3);arr2=(4,5,6);...'
```

Note that for `New-Variable` you cannot prefix the `$` sigil. The *variable name* is `arr1`, even if you refer to it in code as `$arr1` or `(gv arr1).Value` or whatever.

But that's a really strange way to write code in PowerShell. You just don't really provide enough detail so that we would actually know what you're doing.

You can just as well do

```
$arr1 = '(1,2,3)'
$arr2 = '(4,5,6)'
...
```

Comment: Sorry, I quickly put this up last night. Thanks for the help all but I figured this one out. I am pulling this string from a config file and when I am splitting the the string I was getting some random character inserted. I fixed this by trimming $var[0].

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this was happening but when I was splitting my string I was getting some random ascii character in my array.  Able to see this thanks to PowerGUI!!! The solution was to trim the string prior to using it.  (i.e. $var[0].Trim() )